# What does this mean in jquery? $object

Tags: javascript, jquery

say for example I have this code:

`function tester($userInput)
{
this.$userInput1 = userInput;
}`

Comment: It is just a variable name. It is convention to generally prepend `$` to jquery objects

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. That's JavaScript. It sets the `$userInput1` property of `this` to `userInput`.

Comment: It's normal JavaScript. You could use it like: `var a = new tester("input")` and `a.$userInput1` which would return `undefined` since `userInput` in your code is not defined :P

Answer (score 0):

$object doesn't mean anything specific in JavaScript.. its just a variable name.  However if you've included the jQuery library, you can use $ to reference the jQuery library, ex: `$.ajax()` or `$('#element_id')`